# Which Xamarin path to use to see SQLite database with SQLite Editor?

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

I have added a SQLite database to my Xamarin Android app and I thought it would be nice for our tech support people (and me as a developer) to see the database on the device. Right now I can email it but seeing it real time would be nice.

I found an App called SQLite Editor in the Play Store and it uses a 'pseudo path' '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.myappname'.

It found nothing in the Files sub folder and at first nothing in the cache sub folder. After I messed around with the app a bit, some folders with jibberish names showed up in the Cache folder and when I 'drilled' into it, it found my database.

As I used the app, more of these cache folders appeared and these had older versions of my database in them (not sure I liked that but...).

My issue is, how do I reliably know which database is the most current?

I am writing the database to:
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments -> data/user/0/com.companyname.storetrakhh/files/

I tried other some other paths with no real success.

Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData -> /data/user/0/com.companyname.storetrakhh/files/.config

Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData ->
/usr/share/" --> Can't write to.

Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData -> /data/user/0/com.companyname.storetrakhh/files/.local/share/

Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal -> /data/user/0/com.companyname.storetrakhh/files

Environment.SpecialFolder.System -> Empty

Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.CacheDirectory -> /data/user/0/com.companyname.storetrakhh/cache/storetrak.db

Comment: Do you mean the Editor[SQLite Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.sqleditor&hl=en_US&gl=US) ?  We can find that SQLite Editor is for root users. And non-root users can browse and edit databases on the SD card.

Comment: Ouch. Not sure I want to rick a user turning their device into a 'brick'. Thanks.